# How to whitelist IP addresses on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail, sitelock

I used Amazon Lightsail to deploy a wordpress site and it worked like a charm. Now I have the need to restrict the IP addresses that can access on port 80 to the ones associated to the Firewall from SiteLock, and I am looking for the best and cleanest solution.

It looks like in Lightsail simplified version of the world, I can only open a port for public access, or close it.

My only idea now is logging in via SSH and use `iptables`, but I wanted to understand if that's the only way I can do this, or there is something "smarter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now, IPs can be whitelisted from AWS console itself. Go to your Lightsail instance in console, then networking. there you can choose ports to open, and to whitelist IP, check Restrict to IP. then enter whielisted IP or range and save.

reference: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-editing-firewall-rules

Answer (score 4):

This is what I came out with, that actually works, but uses `iptables` which I am not sure is the best option, so the question is still open to get a better solution.

Since SiteLock website says these IP ranges are to be allowed in:

> SiteLock Firewall IP Ranges
>
> 199.83.128.0/21
>
> 198.143.32.0/19
>
> 149.126.72.0/21
>
> 103.28.248.0/22
>
> 45.64.64.0/22
>
> 185.11.124.0/22
>
> 192.230.64.0/18
>
> 107.154.0.0/16
>
> 2a02:e980::/29

I created a script to allow them all, and then close all the rest with an explicit `DROP` rule

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 199.83.128.0/21 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 198.143.32.0/19 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 149.126.72.0/21 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 103.28.248.0/22 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 45.64.64.0/22 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 185.11.124.0/22 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.230.64.0/18 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 107.154.0.0/16 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 2a02:e980::/29 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Comment: Lighsail doesn't allow granular source-IP-based control via security groups the way EC2 does, so... assuming these rules accomplish what you intend, this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot , yes this actually works, but I'll keep hoping to find a better solution, even with a different approach